# Website Hosting Error after Google Cloud Trial Ended

Tags: virtual-machines, hosting

Issue: My website has a hosting error. It was working while I was using a free trial with google cloud and when the trial ended settings changed and the website hasn't been working since. I'm using a VM instance. Maybe there's something simple I'm missing but i'm not sure what.

What I've Tried: I updated my billing and tried resetting it with no luck.

I shared a screenshot of the setup I used. It was from the google cloud free program - https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features

I'm not super technical and any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Website Hosting Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIYjl.png)
[VM Instance Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoeJP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your trial ended so the normal behavior of any service provider is to shutdown the services you use (like virtual machine you use for web).

Pay subscription and as far as you continue to pay you will have services you start.